# Can you use a dataframe to assist with "find and replace" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to clean some Census data where all the States are given a FIPS code instead of the state abbreviation. I want to run something to go through the column with the FIPS code and convert them to the state abbreviation. Find all the 1's and convert them to AL, all the 2's to AK and so one. I know i can do this with ifelse statement but was wondering if there was a more efficient way with out writing 51 ifelse statements. Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Use `merge`? Or match with a named vector?

Comment: Yeah, if you have a separate file matching FIPS codes with state abbreviations there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: Kit, can you provide small sample data to demonstrate the issue? Suggestions are typically much easier (and more usable/relevant to you) if done on similar data structures/names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a try. I'll use data from https://www.census.gov/library/reference/code-lists/ansi/ansi-codes-for-states.html for valid FIPS codes, and make a fake "bad data" frame.

```r
FIPS <- read.table("https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt",
                   sep = "|", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
head(FIPS)
#   STATE STUSAB STATE_NAME  STATENS
# 1    01     AL    Alabama 01779775
# 2    02     AK     Alaska 01785533
# 3    04     AZ    Arizona 01779777
# 4    05     AR   Arkansas 00068085
# 5    06     CA California 01779778
# 6    08     CO   Colorado 01779779
baddata <- data.frame(stateabbr = c("AL", "AK", "22"))
baddata
#   stateabbr
# 1        AL
# 2        AK
# 3        22
```

### Base R

```r
fixeddata <- merge(baddata, FIPS[,c("STATE", "STUSAB")],
                   by.x = "stateabbr", by.y = "STATE", all.x = TRUE)
fixeddata
#   stateabbr STUSAB
# 1        22     LA
# 2        AK   <NA>
# 3        AL   <NA>
fixeddata$stateabbr <- ifelse(is.na(fixeddata$STUSAB), fixeddata$STUSAB, fixeddata$stateabbr)
fixeddata$STUSAB <- NULL
fixeddata
#   stateabbr
# 1        22
# 2      <NA>
# 3      <NA>
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(baddata, FIPS[,c("STATE", "STUSAB")], by = c("stateabbr" = "STATE")) %>%
  mutate(stateabbr = coalesce(STUSAB, stateabbr)) %>%
  select(-STUSAB)
#   stateabbr
# 1        AL
# 2        AK
# 3        LA
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!! I used the dplyr method.